# I want to make a contour/surface plot, which shows the values in the cells, similar to an EFI tuning map

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, contour, surface

I want to make something like this in MATLAB. This is a map which has `x` and `y` axis and a value for the `z` axis with a  color for the magnitude of the `z` value. Basically a countour map which prints values in the matrix on the screen

Sample graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modifying an `imagesc()` Plot

Here is something that might be similar enough by modifying an `imagesc` plot with text annotations and the `line()` function to create the grid. Some axis attributes including axis replacement needed to be done to configure the plot correctly. Unfortunately, it's not a very concise way of doing it but it might satisfy your application.

[image: Imagesc Plot]

```
Engine_Load = [0.35 0.55 0.7 0.87 1 1.15 1.25 1.35 1.45 1.6 1.7 1.8 2 2.2 2.5];
Engine_Speed = (800:400:7600);

%Creating random test data%
[Engine_Load_Grid,Engine_Speed_Grid] = meshgrid(Engine_Load,Engine_Speed);
Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio = rand(length(Engine_Speed),length(Engine_Load));

%Creating the grid structure%
X_Axis = (1:length(Engine_Load));
Y_Axis = (1:length(Engine_Speed));
[X_Grid,Y_Grid] = meshgrid(X_Axis,Y_Axis);

clf;
imagesc('XData',X_Axis,'YData',Y_Axis,'CData',Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio);
xticks(1:1:length(X_Axis));
yticks(1:1:length(Y_Axis));
xlim([0.5 length(X_Axis)+0.5]);
ylim([0.5 length(Y_Axis)+0.5]);
Current_Axis = gca;
Current_Axis.XAxisLocation = 'Top';
grid on;

for Horizontal_Lines = 1: length(yticks)
line([0.5 length(X_Axis)+0.5],[Horizontal_Lines+0.5 Horizontal_Lines+0.5],'color','w','LineWidth',2);
end

for Vertical_Lines = 1: length(yticks)
line([Vertical_Lines+0.5 Vertical_Lines+0.5],[0.5 length(Y_Axis)+0.5],'color','w','LineWidth',2);
end

Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio = flip(Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio);
[Matrix_Height,Matrix_Width] = size(Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio);
for Row_Index = 1: Matrix_Height
    for Column_Index = 1: Matrix_Width
        
    text(Column_Index,Matrix_Height+1-Row_Index,num2str(Estimated_Air_Fuel_Ratio(Row_Index,Column_Index)));
    
    end
end

Current_Figure = gcf;
set(findall(gcf,'type','text'),'HorizontalAlignment','center')
set(Current_Axis,'xtick',X_Axis,'xticklabel',Engine_Load);
set(Current_Axis,'ytick',Y_Axis,'yticklabel',Engine_Speed);
xlabel('Engine Load'); ylabel('Engine Speed');
colorbar

Current_Figure.Position = [0 0 1000 1000];
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: cool thanks! I may try packing this code into a bit of a function for my future use. did you write this one yourself ? And it wont run on my matlab r2015a but I will be updating to MATLAB r2020 and that should do it.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it myself. R2020 should do the trick I'm not sure which version all the functions I used were implemented in. Good plan to pack this all into a function.